# dynamically replace files in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to replace dynamically files in angular, running an AB test. I am using fileReplacements in the angular.json file that angular 6 provides.

**Test1**:

```
            {
             "replace": "src/environments/controls",
             "with": "src/environments/controls_Test1"
            }
```

**Test2**:

```
            {
             "replace": "src/environments/controls",
             "with": "src/environments/controls_Test2"
            }
```

My problem is in the component. How do I configure the path to pick data from controls_Test1 for one Test case?

File1 controls_Test1.ts

```
export const control = 'control_test1';
```

File2 controls_Test2.ts

`export const control = 'control_test2';`

what path shld I have in the component to pick respective constants from the respective files for the AB test.

src/environment/'<'eachTestShldPickup respective Files'>'

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the build takes care of replacing the files in component typescript :-)